# How to run a CSL processor in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, styles, citations, csl

I need to use Citation Style Language (CSL) styles in my Java application but I can't find how to do that. I found a CSL processor written in JavaScript [here](https://bitbucket.org/fbennett/citeproc-js/downloads), but I don't understand how to use it. Can anybody help me please...?

Answer (score 1):

Java is nothing like Javascript. It would be easier to write a new CSL parser from scratch in Java than try to convert a Javascript codebase.

Comment: I just want to call that javascript from my java application.

Comment: I can't understand which file should I call and how to call it.Which parameters should I give.

Comment: If you integrated [v8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) into your project, you can interpret the Javascript that way. But even getting that to work would probably be more work than writing a CSL parser in Java from scratch.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a link to a newly released Java CSL processor.

Answer (score 1):

**Update September 2013**: [citeproc-java](http://michel-kraemer.github.io/citeproc-java/), a Java wrapper around citeproc-js, has just been released.

---

Official documentation for using the [citeproc-js](https://github.com/Juris-M/citeproc-js) CSL processor can be found [here](https://citeproc-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).